# Codec or player for FLV files

Tags: video, flv, video-codecs, gom-player

I have many FLV files and when I play them using Windows Media Player or GOM and try to click on the bar to advance to another part of the video, I find the video pausing for a long time before it responds and plays again.

What codec or player can I use to fast forward through my FLV files?

Comment: VLC always works for me

Comment: We don't even know which codecs you have installed and which alternatives **you** tried. Do you rather want to solve the actual issue of not being able to forward in GOM?

Comment: @slhck I want to solve slow forward/backward response for flv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) is pretty much the standard suggestion, since it bundles a lot of codecs into the install so you don't have to find them all yourself.

If you find yourself just wanting a codec, I believe [FFDShow](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/ffdshow.htm) is able to parse FLVs. If you want a codec pack, [I usually recommend CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/).

Comment: the codec did not solve my problem. only vlc and adobe media player !!.......thanks